# Swift dylib in Rust without using unsafe

Tags: swift, rust, rust-cargo, dylib

Is there is any way to run Swift dylib from Rust without using unsafe? Or is there any way to call the Swift functions from Rust without Rust's `unsafe`? To date whatever I tried I had to use `unsafe`.

Comment: External code requires unsafe, because to rust, every other language is completely unsafe. If you don't want to use unsafe, you need to use only rust. A better question to ask is how to wrap specific external functions with a safe API.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is impossible to call any *external* (FFI) functions from Rust without specifying them as `unsafe`. You have to assert to the compiler that this code upholds **all** rust safety requirements. And since compiler cannot do that, you have to do it manually by using `unsafe` (and of course it *has* to be safe to do it).

To better understand why there is `unsafe` in the language read chapter on [Unsafe Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html) from the Rust Programming Language, and especially [Using extern functions to call external code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code) paragraph.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksander Krauze will check this out.

Answer (score 2):

@AleksanderKrauze is technically correct. Somewhere, there needs to be unsafe code for the FFI. But that doesn't mean that you need to write that unsafe code yourself.
You could for example use something that generates that unsafe code for you. If that something is well-made (i.e. sound), all the code you write will be safe rust, and you won't need to worry about accidental undefined behavior.

[`swift-bridge`](https://github.com/chinedufn/swift-bridge#quick-peek) might be one such something, but I can't vouch for its completeness or soundness.

Comment: Thanks @Caesar. Just came across swift-bridge. Trying it out.